# Driver, COMException errors

Tags: vb.net, wia

I am using the following code to scan documents:

```
Dim manager = New DeviceManager
Dim deviceinfo = manager.DeviceInfos.Cast(Of DeviceInfo)().FirstOrDefault(Function(di) di.Properties("Name").Value = deviceName)
If deviceinfo Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Dim device As Device = deviceinfo.Connect

Dim dlg = New CommonDialog

Dim Item As Item = device.Items(1)
Item.Properties("Bits Per Pixel").Value = 1
Item.Properties("Horizontal Resolution").Value = 200
Item.Properties("Vertical Resolution").Value = 200

Dim img As ImageFile = dlg.ShowTransfer(Item, FormatID.wiaFormatTIFF, False)
```

At the last line, I am receiving 2 different error codes. Sometimes I get `0x8021000E`, which according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630183(v=vs.85).aspx) page, means a `WIA_ERROR_EXCEPTION_IN_DRIVER` error.

Sometimes I get **COMException The remote procedure call failed 0x800706BE**

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552736(v=vs.85).aspx) page, driver errors are logged by default to `%windir%\wiadebug.log`, but I didn't find the any log file there. I did find a file at `%windir%\debug\wiatrace.log` which seems to contain this information. but it doesn't give me anything more than the actual error.

The program is running on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit. The WIA Service is running.

What steps can I take to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do make sure the thread you run this on is an STA thread, the kind you get in a WPF or Winforms app.  Other than that, getting a driver update from the device manufacturer is about your only hope to avoid this.

Comment: Also, check the parameters and make sure (1) all are valid for your device, and (2) you don't have to initialize any that you're not. Some devices don't follow the rules.

Comment: @HansPassant I was initially spinning off a task with Task.Run. Now that I run it synchronously I consistently get COMException.

Comment: @xpda How do I verify what I need to initialize and if the properties are supported?

Answer (score 0):

1) I had a reference to the WIA DLL as if it was not a system COM DLL, but rather an external DLL. Changing this resolved the COM Exception.

2) The WIA driver exception is apparently because I was explicitly setting the resolution values to 200. Without that, the scanning proceeds fine.

On [this page](http://adfwia.codeplex.com/discussions/271348), it is recommended to set the DPI to 150, or to 300 or more, and that some scanners have a problem with DPI of less than 300. (I will update this answer once I have checked this.)